# How to append a string in C# dynamically?

Tags: c#

Thank you in Advance:

I have a parameter which gives the row_count after loading the data.

i need to insert that value into a file, which i am able to do it.

But I need the format in this manner:

if the row_count is 150 then

I am getting only *Param name='INPUT_NUM_RECS value=150/*

But I need the **output** as

**Param name='INPUT_NUM_RECS value=000000150/**

Thank you.

Comment: Something like `$"Param name='INPUT_NUM_RECS value={row_count:000000000}/"`?

Comment: or something like `$"Param name='INPUT_NUM_RECS value={row_count:D9}/"`

Comment: so you want to insert six 0's after value? Or have the number be 9 digits?

Comment: or something like `row_count.ToString("D9")`

Comment: Show the code you use to build up that string. Or is it even a string? Maybe you are showing us a custom command / insert object/type? It is hard to help without code.

Comment: Key point - you need **formatting**, specificly **leading zeros formatting**. Google is your friend now.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that 150 is an int variable name num.

```
int num = 15;

string output = $"Param name='INPUT_NUM_RECS value={num:D9}"
```

Here using D9 we will place the int value with leading zeroes if the number of digits in num is less than 9.

```
Number of leading zeroes = 9 - digits in num
```

If number of digits in num is more than 9, **num will not be truncated**